# Sylow permutability and generalizations

Tags: group-theory

DEFINITION.
Let $G$ be a finite group and let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Then 
 $H$  is called nearly S-permutable in $G$ if for every prime $p$ such that $(p,|H|)=1$, and for every subgroup $K$
of $G$ containing $H$,  the normalizer $N_{K}(H)$ contains some $p$-Sylow subgroup of $K$, we shall denote this by ($H$ is $NSP$ in $G$).

DEFINITION. 
A finite group $G$ is called $T_{nsp}$- group if nearly $S$-permutability is
transitive among subgroups of $G$. That is, if $A$ is $NSP$ in $B$, and $B$ is $NSP$ in $G$, then $A$ is $NSP$ in $G$.

PROBLEM 
Let $G$ be a finite supersolvable group. Prove that if  a $p$-Sylow subgroup $P$ of $G$ has a subgroup $H$ not nearly S-permutable in  $N_G(P)$ then $G$ is not $T_{nsp}$- group.

PROOF. We know that $H$ is $NSP$ in $P$(Since $P$ has no other prime divisors except $p$).  $P$ is $NSP$ in $N_G(P)$ (this follows from the fact that: normality implies nearly S-permutability). So, what we trivially get, is that $N_G(P)$ is not $T_{nsp}$- group. I cannot see why $G$ must NOT be $T_{nsp}$- group.

ANY ADVICE, PLEASE!